# having trouble installing ubuntu studio 13.04

Tags: installation, dual-boot, live-usb, ubuntu-studio

I am currently trying to install Ubuntu Studio 13.04 along side Windows 7.

When I boot into the USB stick, I make the proper selections and it reboots.  When I boot into Windows 7 and open `wubi.exe`, I am given a choice to run demo or learn more (I don't get the screen that allows you to select drive size and what not). It says that I can install from the demo, so i make the proper selection, then it reboots.

How can I overcome this and install Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: How did you create the USB?