# Installed Ubuntu Studio, got standard version

Tags: installation, ubuntu-studio

I tried to install 13.04 alongside with Windows 7, but it completely fails and just reboots.  So now I tried to install 12.10, which I have had previous success, fail.

I ran the demo and it worked just fine. It was exactly what I expected.  I used Wubi in Win 7 to install Ubuntu Studio, everything seemed fine until I restarted and was booted into Ubuntu 12.10, not Studio.  I have none of the production software, and the interface is completely different.

How can I get the version of Ubuntu Studio?

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu! You've already asked this question: [having trouble installing ubuntu studio 13.04](http://askubuntu.com/q/322264/159545). Please consider deleting one of the posts (preferably this one).

Answer (score 1):

Do you get a "Grub version 2.0" menu when you boot up or do you get the Windows or Other menu? The Grub menu says Grub version 2.0 at the top of the screen. If you get the Grub menu, you can update that menu if it does not show all installed operating systems. 
    grub-mkconfig
You may need to run this as sudo.
More help can be found here.
http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/